# how to use the same environment in terminal with what's in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm a greener in anaconda. Forgive me if I ask a stupid question. The following is the issue I faced. And thanks a lot in advance to take your time.

I installed anaconda2 and used jupyter notebook to run the python program.
One program used opencv. When I run the problem in notebook, there's no problem at all.
While when I run the program with terminal, there's following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classify.py", line 9, in <module>
    import imutils
  File "/home/oakcloud/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/imutils/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .convenience import translate
  File "/home/oakcloud/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/imutils/convenience.py", line 6, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /home/oakcloud/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/../../libopencv_objdetect.so.3.3)
```

There's only one conda env named base in my PC, and I have such problem after I enter the env with **source activate base** command. I had thought notebook should use the same env.

The issue above complained the lib dismatch. I checked the lib in sys directory:

```
oakcloud@ubuntu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ pwd
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
oakcloud@ubuntu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ll  libstdc++.so.*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      19 Feb  6 12:07 libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.21
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1566440 Feb  6 12:21 libstdc++.so.6.0.21
```

To fix the problem, I think I can just replace the lib with a new version.

While I found in anaconda, the lib is already installed：

```
oakcloud@ubuntu:~/anaconda2$ ll ./pkgs/libstdcxx-ng-7.2.0-h7a57d05_2/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 oakcloud oakcloud 32 Oct  6  2017 ./pkgs/libstdcxx-ng-7.2.0-h7a57d05_2/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.so.6 -> ../../../lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.24*
```

So my question is how can I use the same setting in shell with what's in notebook?

cheers,

Julian.